# Count case statement with comparing this month and previous month

Tags: sql, date, count, case

I have data with monthly dates, IDs, and visits. I would like to write a query that counts per month where the current month visit number equals zero and the previous month is not equal to zero.
Something like that;

```
select month,
       count(case when visits = 0 (this month) and (previous month) =! 0 then 1 else 0 end ) 
from ..
```

So I want to see how many ids were visiting zero times this month but were active the previous one. Could you please help me with that?

my data looks like this;

```
|ID  |  DATE       |VISIT|
|----|-------------|-----
|1   | 2015-01-01  | 10  |
|2   | 2015-01-01  |  3  |
|3   | 2015-01-01  |  0  |
|1   | 2015-02-01  |  0  |
|2   | 2015-02-01  |  1  |
|3   | 2015-02-01  |  2  |
```

For example, the answer from this example table, I have only one ID (ID number 1) provides the condition.

Comment: Which database+version are you using? Like SQL Server, MySQL?

Comment: I am using SQL Server